# python libsvm: used function: svm_predict(), what means with output "p_val"

Tags: python, libsvm

I use python libsvm function:

```
p_label, p_acc, p_val = svm_predict(y, x, model)
```

There had some problem at output "p_val ".

Problem at task is three label(+1, 0, -1)classification.

I don't know how it predict label. i write my python code like that:

```
y, x = svm_read_problem('test.data')
m = svm_train( y[0:900], x[0:900], opt )
p_label, p_acc, p_val = svm_predict( y[900:910], x[900:910], m )
```

There is output:

**p_label(predict class) = [p_val(a list of decision values or probability estimates)]** :

- -1.0 = [1.0449524711949485, 1.4113796513344399, 1.0120255052284173],
- -1.0 = [1.0969353852717083, 0.9601933938910249, 0.3407227530552793],
- -1.0 = [0.9608561833833849, 1.4704797796797964, 1.1354416470136237],
- -1.0 = [0.5629743031525207, 0.6418911014217697, 0.5962484893807319],
- -1.0 = [0.9998935746528146, 0.999862936350972, 0.4352865894491481],
- -1.0 = [0.5899682420542727, 0.759898755977403, 0.45466598793345214],
- -1.0 = [0.8029330343073868, 0.9569608406914972, 0.7464642555671487],
- -1.0 = [1.206590596563432, 0.9205300145992189, -0.25622479105667184],
- -1.0 = [0.75271162867797, 0.9999549323095839, 0.8478570959739556],
- 0.0 = [-0.07135185943489092, 0.483809082370377, 0.764341953305053]]

---

I have no idea with relationship between "predict label" and "a list of decision values" .

please give me some advice!

Answer (score 0):

`p_val` is the probability of getting one of your labes for each data-point

Comment: Thanks for answer! such as first answer：-1.0 = [1.0449524711949485, 1.4113796513344399, 1.0120255052284173]，can you explain how it predicts?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should input '-b 1' in the function svm_predict. That is one of the predicting_options. Then p_val will be the probability of getting the labels.